# Ferromagnetism and electrical conductivity

Tags: electromagnetism

Are ferromagnetic materials good conductors of electricity? If yes, please explain with proper examples.

Comment: Do you mean: do ferromagnetic materials *tend* to be good conductors of electricity in general?  Or are you just looking for specific examples, like (say) iron?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about ferromagnetic insulators at room temperature, but it looks like there are such materials at lower temperatures (http://www.cdm.ucsb.edu/pages/research4.html ).

Answer (score 0):

yes generally they are. eg.- iron, nickel, cobalt. thus they also have eddy current losses.
whereas Al, Cu are good conductors without being ferromagnetic

Answer (score -1):

Ferromagnetic materials are conductors of electricity up to about 2 KHz.  Beyond that frequency, they do not conduct because the dipoles no longer rotate and the high frequency energy (hamonics) produce eddy currents and is absorb.

Comment: And yet iron, which is a ferromagnet, will conduct at frequencies far above 2kHz.